# JBoss 5.1 jsp dev mode: Always recompile jsps?

Tags: jsp, jboss, compilation

Is there a setting somewhere in JBossAS 5.1GA that forces a recompile of JSPs on each http request?

I guess I could delete the work dir each time but there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in this file: JBoss_install_directory/server/default/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/conf/web.xml.

There is an entry named "development".  Set this to true.

Sorry to not have an example of this file.  I no longer use JBoss 5, so my notes only contained the path the the file.

Comment: jboss_install_directory\server\default\deployers\jbossweb.deployer\web.xml. Thanks.